# Cannot return to userinput line and cannot print out the board

Tags: c++

I have been working for an hour on this function. I try to get the return to go back to the user question "Enter the size board" when it goes to 2nd for statement, but it ends the program instead. Other issue is the program stops on the line, "int makeBoard[row][column];" when I ran the debug so therefore it causes not to print out the board. Whats up with that??

```
void showBoard()
{
 int i;
 int boardSize;

 if(i > 3 || i < 13)
 {
      cout << "Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: ";
      cin >> i;
      cout << "The number you entered is: " << i;
      if(i < 4 || i > 12)
      {
           cout << "\nYou entered the invalid number, read the direction again.\n";
           return;
      }
      cout << " ";
      cout << "\nGame ends when you reach 1024.\n";
 }

 int row = boardSize;
 int column = boardSize;
 int x, y;
 int makeBoard[row][column];

 for(x = 0; x < row; x++)
 {
       for(y = 0; y < column; y++)
       {
             makeBoard[x][y] = '.';
             printf(" %c", makeBoard[x][y]);
       }
       printf("\n\n");
 }
```

}

Comment: You never assign boardSize a value as far as I can see, so guess your compiler assigns it a value of 0 which would obviously cause your for-loops to not run at all.

Comment: What does 1024 refer to?  How does one reach it by specifying the board size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you have asked to the user ,was for variable "i". Whereas,row and coloumn are given value of uninitialized variable "Boardsize". 
You need to put "Boardsize" at the place of the "i" or vice versa.

and also in the conditional statement for handling error, you have used return ,whereas you are not returning any value....so for that case I recommend you to use "cin>>boardsize; " at the place of "return" to handle error more precisely.

Makeboard array needs to be of char type to print '.' or as int, the block will print "46",which is ASCII value of '.'

```
int main() {

    int boardSize;

    if(boardSize > 3 || boardSize < 13) {

  cout << "Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: ";

  cin >> boardSize;        // take input for boardsize ,not i

  cout << "The number you entered is: " << boardSize;

  if(boardSize < 4 || boardSize > 12)
  {
       cout << "\nYou entered the invalid number, read the direction again.\n";

       cin>>boardSize;  // change return by this statement 
  }
  cout << " ";
  cout << "\nGame ends when you reach 1024.\n";

}

 int row = boardSize;  //earlier the problem was in this line
 int column = boardSize; //also here
 int x, y;

char makeBoard[row][column]; // also you need this array of char data type to print '.'

 for(x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < column; y++) {
        makeBoard[x][y] = '.';

        cout<<makeBoard[x][y];
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}  

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It helped! However, I managed to print out dots by swtiching from cout << makeboard[x][y] to printf(" %c", makeboard[x][y]

Answer (score 1):

The following, critical, variables are not initialize: `i` and `boardSize`.

If you do manage to get past the first `if` statement, nothing initializes the `boardSize` variable.

**Edit 1:**
The variable `i` is only used to annoy the program.  It is not assigned to anything.

**Edit 2:**
Your board is declared to be signed integers, but you assign it characters.  Shouldn't it be declared a board of characters?

**Edit 3: -- Printing the board**
If you add an additional column to the board, you could use the last column to hold '\n'.  That way you would only need one print statement for each row.

**Edit 4: putchar vs. printf**
If you know you are printing a character, use `putchar` rather than `printf`.  The `printf` function has extra overhead because it has to parse the formatting string.  The `putchar` function takes the character and writes it to the output; no formatting required, more efficient.

If you propagate this idea, you could append another row.  The first column of this row would contain '\0'.  This change, combined with the above, allows you to print the board with one print statement and no `for` loop. Wow!

Comment: Excellent information. Thank you so much. At least I learned something new to understand C++ more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if you don't understand exactly what the 'return' keyword is designed to do.   Similarly, your code has many mistakes in it. I'd suggest reading a tutorial or C++ book.

Return is designed to exit the current function (i.e. if you have return at the beginning of the function, it would literally do nothing).

Also, it's a mistake to not initialize your variables upon declaring them. Instead of int i; consider int i=-1;. Otherwise, the result will be undefined. i could be equal to 10 or 100000 or -20002393.

      `int i=-1;
      while(true) // Do this forever
      {
           cout << "Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: ";
           cin >> i;
           cout << "The number you entered is: " << i;
           if(i < 4 || i > 12)
           {
              cout << "\nYou entered the invalid number, read the direction again.\n";
           }
           else break; // You can leave the loop!
      }
      cout << " ";
      cout << "\nGame ends when you reach 1024.\n";`

This isn't the best way to do it, but I hope it gives you an idea.  Also, please go through some tutorials before you post rather basic questions. It doesn't appear as if you have a basic understanding of C++ at this time.  But, best of luck and hope I could help!